# Build of MAUI project fails after update of dotnet workload

Tags: c#, maui

I have a .NET MAUI project that was building successfully until I ran the dotnet workload update command. After the update I get a series of MSB4018 errors. This is the beginning of the list of errors; the rest are very similar and point to issues finding version 8.0.2 of the sdk which appears to have been removed with the workload update command.

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/17.2.8043/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1214,3): error MSB4018: The "AOTCompile" task failed unexpectedly. [/Users/davidrutter/Projects/simul_bcfo1/aspnet-core/src/Simul_BCFO.Maui/Simul_BCFO.Maui.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/17.2.8043/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1214,3): error MSB4018: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.osx-x64.Cross.ios-arm64/8.0.2/Sdk/../tools/mono-aot-cross' with working directory '/Users/davidrutter/Projects/simul_bcfo1/aspnet-core/src/Simul_BCFO.Maui'. No such file or directory))) (One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.osx-x64.Cross.ios-arm64/8.0.2/Sdk/../tools/mono-aot-cross' with working directory '/Users/davidrutter/Projects/simul_bcfo1/aspnet-core/src/Simul_BCFO.Maui'. No such file or directory))) [/Users/davidrutter/Projects/simul_bcfo1/aspnet-core/src/Simul_BCFO.Maui/Simul_BCFO.Maui.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
```

Any help solving this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will fix your specific situation, but I experience issues like this occasionally after workload updates, too.

There sometimes are AOT compilation errors when building for iOS that are related to the processor architecture.

When this happens, I usually delete the *bin* and *obj* folders, make sure to build against the correct processor architecture of the target machine and try again.

For example, I usually also need to comment/remove these lines from the *.csproj* file:

```xml
<RuntimeIdentifier>iossimulator-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
<ForceSimulatorX64ArchitectureInIDE>true</ForceSimulatorX64ArchitectureInIDE>
```

That's because I'm building from Windows with a connection to a Mac mini 2 that has an M2 chip, while my colleagues use older x64-based Macs.